# Using the same event handler for multiple buttons

Tags: vb.net

I have 15 buttons created through design.

I want them to have a background picture whenever I click on any of them, for example:

- If I click on button11 then its background will be "Hello.jpg"
- If  click button12 then its background will be become "Hello.jpg"

Is there a method to write a code instead of writing code for individual button?

The code should detect which button I clicked and then change its background.

```
    Private Sub e_11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles e_11.Click
e_11.Image = Image.FromFile("E:\battleship\Explode.gif")
End Sub
```

Is there a way that handles every button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can bind the same method to multiple controls:

```
Private Sub MyButtons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles e_1.Click, e_2.Click, e_3.Click, ...

    Dim myButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    myButton.Image = Image.FromFile("E:\battleship\Explode.gif")
End Sub
```